# Is my unregistered account lost?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts, unregistered-users

I recently asked a question with an unregistered account here:

[Do I really need to stay the full 2 weeks' notice?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21438/do-i-really-need-to-stay-the-full-2-weeks)

This account now has reputation, and my question has generated discussion I'd really like to participate in.  Unfortunately, however, my cookies have been deleted since I created that account.  Now, there does not appear to be any way to recover or even log into the account.  When I clicked the emailed link to register the account with a password, this account was created instead.

Unfortunately, this account does me no good, as I'd really prefer to continue the discussion with my old account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this up for you. For future readers, if you can't use /users/account-recovery to regain access to your account (and then register it), you can use /contact to let us know about the problem - we'll usually get you fixed up within 24-48 hours.